# Instantiate each object in an array - Java

Tags: java, arrays, object-to-string

I'm not getting any errors from the following code but my `toString` is returning null for the instance.

```
Shoe shoe[]  = new Shoe[10];
shoe[0] = new Shoe();
shoe[0].setPosition(12, 34);
```

If I instantiate an object normally and call its `setPosition` the `toString` returns the correct position. But when trying to do this through the array it returns null.

Comment: This is fine, I expect the bug lies elsewhere, try debuggers or print statements, or pasting more code here

Comment: Whats the code of your `toString()`?

Comment: I strongly recommend learning to use a debugger.  But if you are determined to ask a question here, then please give us more to work with than just three lines.

Comment: Ok thanks. I had a brain fart. all sorted.

Comment: Please show us your default constructor for class `Shoe` (if you have one) and `setPosition` method.

Comment: Where are is called `toString()` i can't see in the code you post!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your code. Based on your comments there is likely lsome interplay between setPosition() and toString(). You should revisit that logic.

As per the code you've outlined in the description, it is good Java code.

Comment: Such response belongs in comments.

Comment: It was a silly mistake I had another object called shoes in the toString which refernced nothing. I just didnt see it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @DanielLerps - not an excuse for posting a non-answer as an answer

Comment: Hey I can comment now!! :-D